# Python Script tool not supporting Selected features only option in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I'm create a python script tool in QGIS that is working perfect. However when I use the "Selected features only" checkbox to run my script in just one polygon feature it returns the following error:

> Could not load source layer for INPUT: invalid value

Here in how I'm initiating the variable in `initAlgorithm` and `processAlgorithm` functions:

```
def initAlgorithm(self, config=None):
    self.addParameter(
            QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource(
                self.INPUT_POL,
                self.tr('Property Polygon'),
                [QgsProcessing.TypeVectorPolygon]
            )
        )
        
def processAlgorithm(self, parameters, context, feedback):
    shp_roi = self.parameterAsSource(parameters, self.INPUT_POL, context)
```

How could I overcome this issue?

Comment: Code seems absolutely correct. Does this issue repeat on different data sourses or layers?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal working example?